# Journey Data in Mobile Push

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush, gtl

I am trying to personalize a Push message with Journey Data coming from API call. I am trying to use GTL but it is not working.

```
{{Event.Event-Definition-Key.Attribute-name}}
```

Thanks!